# Java Reverse Engineering Tutorial

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, bytecode

I am interested in how the reverse-engineering on java bytecode is conducted. Can anyone recommend some useful tutorials for me?

I have read some articles on this topic already:
1. [The class File Format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html)
2. [Java bytecode](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/)

These two articles gave a lot of information about bytecode. However, non of them actually talks about the way to reverse engineer it, like how a snap of code is able to be mapped back to an if condition block or a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: Just google for java decompiler: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+decompiler There are several available

Comment: They are the done decompilers. My purpose is to know how they do it.

Comment: Fair enough, I was not clear about your intent. Although looking at their source should be of help, too.

Comment: True! I am thinking of doing some source-bytecode comparison if I cannot get a good book/tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read some books about the Java virtual machines, to get a better understand on how it works:

1. [Programming for the Java(TM) Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309726)
2. [Java(TM) Virtual Machine Specification, The (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201432943)